# CSS: Div spanning over floated div

Tags: css

I have a left floated div and the div after it is spanning over the left floated div.

Look here http://www.kienitz.it/kienitz_cms/referenzen/.

I want to have it like this: http://www.kienitz.it/kienitz_cms/testtt2/.
This is all in wordpress and this last example I made with the onethird and onethirdlast shortcodes. Don't know what happened.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Regards.

Comment: In your browser you can start-up the development tools and closely inspect the CSS of your elements.

Comment: Thanks, I am using this big-time. If you do it, you can see that I did not do anything different to the working example. And there you can see only, that the div is spanning over the floated div.

Comment: what change are you exactly looking for?

Comment: Hey thank you. I wanted the right div to start after the left div, but only the content started right of the right div. I had to put the right div into `float:left`also, then I had the wished result. Thank you all for your contribution!!

Answer (score 0):

**Checked your websites**

Actually i didn't understand wot chage is you needed

But just try this ... need to change the CSS property `float:left` to right of Class 'firmen'

```
    .firmen {
         float: right;
         width: 450px;
         }
```

Comment: Chage? I don't understand what you are saying. 
But to change it to right it mixes all the logic of the site up.
Still the "technologien" class is spanning the whole width though. :)